# Location of the BIOS battery on a Toshiba Portege z20t

Tags: bios, toshiba-laptop

I'm currently trying to reset a BIOS password on an old Toshiba Portege z20t to allow me to change the boot order and reformat the laptop with a fresh copy of Windows 10...

Unfortunately I've hit a wall trying to find the BIOS battery.

If anyone has any ideas, thanks in advance!

It seems I can't post a picture of the board due to only just making this account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't locate the battery at all - i'm not sure to this day if there even is one, and if there is...it's very well hidden.

To solve the issue I removed the m.2. SSD from the laptop and plugged it into a PC, then formatted it using windows on a boot-able USB.

Once in, windows was able to remove the BIOS password.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can try using the tools on Hirens boot cd. https://www.hirensbootcd.org/

You can download the ISO, use a tool to create a bootable usb using a software like rufus usb creator. https://rufus.ie/en_IE.html

Boot into the usb and there are a lot of useful tools. I have never used this tool, but I remember seeing a tool to change bios passwords, and I do not know if it will work on your specific bios/motherboard, but it would not hurt to try!

Comment: But what if you can't even boot past the BIOS? I think that is why the OP want's to hard-reset the BIOS.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately i'm unable to get past the BIOS, so it seems like the only option is to remove the battery. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @series0ne It seems like he can boot past the bios, just not boot into the bios and make any changes because the bios is locked. If usb booting in enabled, most likely is, OP can remove hard drive and boot into the usb and change the password. Unless another boot device is enabled before usb and it will not failover to the usb boot.

Comment: @Avertious Are not able to boot past the bios or boot into the bios? If you can boot into your current version of Windows 10, you are past the bios. If you cannot get into the bios because it is locked with a password, you are not able to get into the bios.

Comment: @MatthewValdez I can get to Windows login (Where there's an old locked account and can go no further) and then when trying to access the BIOS from boot - that's where i'm hit with a BIOS password - which doesn't allow me to do anything apart from enter a password.

Comment: @Avertious Ok, so there is a chance my method can still work. You will need to create the usb, disconnect your hard drive when your laptop is powered off. Plug in the usb, and power on your computer and hope that you get prompted with something along the lines "Press any key to continue." Because ideally, we hope that usb booting is enabled, which is usually turned on, and since it cannot find a hard drive to boot into, it will boot into the usb. If you can boot into the usb, there should be a tool you can use to change the bios password, if there isn't, you may need to get an older version.

Answer (score 0):

After [looking at this article](http://www.myfixguide.com/manual/toshiba-portege-z30-a-disassembly/),  It looks like a non conventional bios battery with leads on it.

[image]

Comment: I have two very similar looking parts on the Z20t, connecting to the motherboard with the first using a black and blue cable and the second using a black and white cable. (Would be a lot easier to explain If i could upload images). But i'm reluctant to unplug them as i'm not 100% sure of their purpose.

Comment: No harm in unplugging them. Most modern laptops will not reset bios password by disconnecting cmos battery.  Reassemble it and power up, enter the wrong password 3 times and see if the bios outputs a code, then post it here in the comments, I may be able to generate a master password.

Comment: No text output unfortunately - just a long beep after each incorrect attempt